# RuntimeError: size mismatch m1: [a x b], m2: [c x d]

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

Can anyone help me in this.? I am getting below error. I use Google Colab. How to Solve this error.?

> size mismatch, m1: [64 x 100], m2: [784 x 128] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:2070

Below Code I am trying to Run.

```
    import torch
    from torch import nn
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    from torchvision import datasets, transforms

    # Define a transform to normalize the data
    transform = 
    transforms.Compose([transforms.CenterCrop(10),transforms.ToTensor(),])
    # Download the load the training data
    trainset = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data/', download=True, 
    train=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, 
    shuffle=True)

    # Build a feed-forward network
    model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 128),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(128, 
    64),nn.ReLU(),nn.Linear(64, 10))

    # Define the loss
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

   # Get our data
   images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
   # Faltten images
   images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)

   # Forward pass, get our logits
   logits = model(images)
   # Calculate the loss with the logits and the labels
   loss = criterion(logits, labels)
   print(loss)
```

Answer (score 8):

All you have to care is `b=c` and you are done:

```
m1: [a x b], m2: [c x d]
```

`m1` is `[a x b]` which is `[batch size x in features]`

`m2` is `[c x d]` which is `[in features x out features]`

Comment: how can i solve this error RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [4 x 2048], m2: [1568 x 10]?

Answer (score 6):

You have a size mismatch!
Your first layer of `model` expects a 784-dim input (I assume you got this value by 28x28=784, the size of MNIST digits).
However, your `trainset` applies [`transforms.CenterCrop(10)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.CenterCrop) - that is it crops a 10x10 region from the center of the image, and thus your input dimension is actually 100.

To summarize:

- Your first layer: `nn.Linear(784, 128)` expects a 784-dim input and outputs a 128-dim hidden feature vector (per input). This layer's weight matrix is thus `[784 x 128]` ("`m2`" in your error message).
- Your input is center cropped to 10x10 pixels (total 100-dim), and you have `batch_size=64` such images at each batch, total `[64 x 100]` input size ("`m1`" in your error message).
- You cannot compute a dot-product between matrices with mismatching sizes: 100 != 784, therefore pytorch gives you this error.