# RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [192 x 68], m2: [1024 x 68] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:268

Tags: pytorch

I'm getting a size mismatch error that I can't understand.

```
(Pdb) self.W_di
Linear(in_features=68, out_features=1024, bias=True)
(Pdb) indices.size()
torch.Size([32, 6, 68])
(Pdb) self.W_di(indices)
*** RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [192 x 68], m2: [1024 x 68] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653099582/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:268
```

Why is there a mismatch?
Maybe because of the way I defined the weight in `forward` (instead of `_init_`)?

This is how I defined `self.W_di`:

```
def forward(self):

    if self.W_di is None:
        self.W_di_weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(mL_n * 2,1024).to(device))
        self.W_di_bias = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1024).to(device))                  

    self.W_di = nn.Linear(mL_n * 2, 1024)
    self.W_di.weight = self.W_di_weight
    self.W_di.bias = self.W_di_bias

    result = self.W_di(indices)
```

Any pointer would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to create your network in the `forward` method as it gets created anew every time you run it (unless you did that on purpose). I'm not sure whether the network is able to learn this way. I'm not entirely sure why there is a mismatch but the `192` comes from `32 x 6` which are the first two dimensions of `indices`.

Comment: I'd suggest you try `32 x 6 x 68 = 13056` as `in_features` of your Linear layer.

Comment: Hi Florian, I initialized them in `forward` on purpose:  https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dynamic-parameter-declaration-in-forward-function/427

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761629/5884955) in general you may set

```
self.W_di = nn.Linear(mL_n * 2, 68)
```

Or increase the in features.

Answer (score 0):

generally we also face this error in cnn, when your input image is not resized to expected size of the model.